# Geocoding function will not work, I keep getting the same error message

Tags: r, geocoding, ggmap, google-geocoder

```
Alex %>%
  geocode(address = 'Address', method = "google",  lat = latitude, long = longitude)

Error in geocode(., address = "Address", method = "google", lat = latitude,  :
is.character(location) is not TRUE
```

I am trying to get coordinates for +17k addresses. The geocode function has worked fine before now but I realized I wasn't putting in the full address, I was only inputting the street address without city or state and getting wildly different coordinates.

For reproducibility I've got some random example data to test with and I've got it in 2 different datasets. One where the address is complete in one column and another dataset where the address is broken up into multiple columns for city, state, and zip code. I've tried both datasets and they both give me the exact same error code.

This dataset is called Alex.

| ID | Address |
| --- | --- |
| 120 | 200 Walmart Way, Morehead, KY 40351 |
| 121 | 131 Jessica Lane, Olive Hill, KY 41164 |
| 122 | 125 Flemingsburg Rd, Morehead, KY 40351 |

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidygeocoder)
library(ggmap)
```

Those are the packages I've got loaded, all of the columns in the Alex table are character type, not numeric, and the table itself is:

```
class(Alex)

[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

I have a Google API key registered and nothing is working. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you mention the package you are usin? (I assume ggmap but I am not sure). For my geocoding need I am using DEGAUSS (https://degauss.org/dht/index.html), I have never try the r package but directly the docker container that is working great and recommend it.

Comment: It has been a long time since I've used Google to geocode, it was back when you didn't need an API key and I didn't use R. However, in order to maximise the chances of an accurate match, back then each 'part' of the address required comma delimiting e.g. "11809 Skyview Dr, Alexandria, KY 41001, USA". You could try stripping out those "." and concatenating your separate column data into a new column as a delimited string using something like `df$address <- paste0(streetnum_and_name, ", ", city, ", ", state, " ", zip, ", USA")`. I find it helps to add country too, as in the example code.

Comment: So, it was a load order problem! I did have both ggmap and tidygeocoder loaded at the same time and that was part of the issue. Now, however, I'm running into a different problem where it's giving me the following error.

Error in is.null(arg) || is.character(arg) || is.numeric(arg) || is.na(arg) : 
  'length = 3' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

Comment: It only does this with the method = "google" and I find the "osm" method to be inaccurate in providing coordinates. I'm sticking with the Google API and right now I'm just trying to solve the new error message.

Comment: Good that you solved one issue! it seems you have some cleaning to do in your data set (hard to tell but that is my first guess. )

Answer (score 1):

this a solution using [DeGAUSS](https://degauss.org/using_degauss.html)

You will need to install docker (just follow https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/ for your OS).

```r
# this is easier for everyone to copy paste your example
alex <- data.frame(
  ID = c(120:124),
  Address = c("200 Walmart Way, Morehead, KY 40351",
        "131 Jessica Lane, Olive Hill, KY 41164",
        "125 Flemingsburg Rd, Morehead, KY 40351"
    

# I did not include the date, degauss prefer that you only use "id"
# and ""address"
 
names(alex) <- tolower(names(alex)) #  degauss is picky with address column name

# degauss take a csv as an argument
write.csv(alex, "alex.csv", row.names = FALSE)

# calling degauss container from R, system2 could have been nicer
system("docker run --rm -v $PWD:/tmp ghcr.io/degauss-org/geocoder:3.3.0 alex.csv")

# see the results
read.csv("alex_geocoder_3.3.0_score_threshold_0.5.csv")
```

One of the address was imprecise (the first one)

```r
| ID | Address | latitude | longitude
| ---| ---------|----|----|
| 120 | 200 Walmart Way, Morehead, KY 40351 | 36.2014 | -83.4821 |
| 121 | 131 Jessica Lane, Olive Hill, KY 41164 | 38.2971| -83.1813|
| 122 | 125 Flemingsburg Rd, Morehead, KY 40351| 38.1779 | -83.4395 |
```

Comment: Can you provide the coordinates you got? Any that I've seen are inaccurate, which is why I'm trying the Google API.

Comment: I will edit the answers with the lat/long value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Google API key for replicating this, but using one of the other geocoding service provides, `geocode(method="osm")`, does return a valid result of your data, albeit OpenStreetMap Nominatum couldn't geocode every address.

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
    ID Address                                     lat  long
  <int> <chr>                                     <dbl> <dbl>
1   200 Walmart Way, Morehead, KY 40351         38.2014 -83.4821 
2   131 Jessica Lane, Olive Hill, KY 41164      38.2971 -83.1813
3   125 Flemingsburg Rd, Morehead, KY 40351     38.1779 -83.4395
```

It might also be a conflict between the two of the packages you have loaded. `ggmap` also has a `geocode()` function with a named argument of `location`, which must be a character vector of street address or place names. Just to make sure, try specifying which `geocode()` function you want to use with `tidygeocoder::geocode(address = "Address", method = "google", lat = latitude, long = longitude)`.

Edit: after getting a Google API key for their geocoding service and resolving the package conflict, the function returns (hopefully) accurate results, so the problem may lie somewhere upstream that isn't shown here?

```
alex <- data.frame(
  ID = c(120:124),
  Address = c(
    "200 Walmart Way, Morehead, KY 40351",
    "131 Jessica Lane, Olive Hill, KY 41164",
    "125 Flemingsburg Rd, Morehead, KY 40351",
  )
)

result <- geocode(
  alex,
  address = 'Address',
  method = 'google',
  lat = latitude,
  long = longitude
)

View(result)
```

Which then shows the following in the View pane:

| ID | Address | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | 200 Walmart Way, Morehead, KY 40351 | 38.2014 | -83.4821 |
| 121 | 131 Jessica Lane, Olive Hill, KY 41164 | 38.2971 | -83.1813 |
| 122 | 125 Flemingsburg Rd, Morehead, KY 40351 | 38.1779 | -83.4395 |

Comment: So, none of those coordinates are accurate for the addresses listed. Which is why I'm not using the "osm" method anymore, it is consistently inaccurate. You were right about the packages though!

Comment: Gotcha! I updated my answer now that the package conflicts were addressed, but that seems to address the error you've described, at least based on the sample code you provided originally.

Comment: keep in mind that geocoding engines can make different design choice. One example is when finding a street but not the address number: some engine will reference the "beginning" other will do the "middle" of it. Sometimes they have different categories of precision and sometime same name but different meaning.   This could explain different result between them.